# How to autowire / inject NULL for an interface type parameter?

Tags: symfony

I followed the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces) to use an interface as type-hint for a method parameter and to update `service.yaml` to tell the autowire process which class should be injected for this interface.

So, in the following example the paramter `$some` of type `SomeInterface` is autowired with a `SomeClass` instance:

```
// The interface
interface SomeInterface { }

// The method to be autowired
public function doSomething(SomeInterface $some) { }

// service.yaml
Name\Space\SomeInterface: '@Name\Space\SomeClass'
```

While this works without any problem, I would like to know **if it possible to inject `null` instead?**

Background is, that `doSomething(SomeInterface $some)` is part of a custom bundle which I would like to use in different projects of mine. The Bundle does not know/care if the later projects has/offers a `SomeClass` and thus providing the parameter should be optional.

So I would like to let autowire inject `null` as default and let the project decide whether to provide an implementation or not.

This did not work:

```
// service.yaml
Name\Space\SomeInterface: ~

OR

Name\Space\SomeInterface: null
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I feel quite dump. Sometimes the solution is way to simple... :-)

Simply provide `null` as default value directly in the methods parameter list:

```
public function doSomething(SomeInterface $some = null) { }
```

I will leave the question and my answer here, in case someone stumbles over the same problem. If this is not OK just delete the question.